# Is there a compilation of the various etymologies of the words for "library" across Europe?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics

The various European languages (as a geographic entity, and excluding the Uralics) present an interesting distribution in their words for "library". In particular, English, Irish, Welsh, Basque, Maltese, and a rare few others have a word derived from Latin *liber* "book", such as our own *library*.

Basically every other language in the group has some variant of ~*bibliotek*, descended from Latin *bibliotheca* "library".

Is there any single discussion of why each language has ended up with whichever word it has today, as opposed to individual etymological dictionaries for every language? I'm very interested in reading such a self-contained work.

To clarify, I'm particularly interested in *historical* reasons for why the words got to where they did, as opposed to just etymological genealogies.

Comment: I'd appreciate advice on why my question warranted a downvote and how I could improve it. I checked the [help page](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this SE and questions requesting "papers/articles on a given topic" are fine. Moreover my question doesn't seem to meet any of the [don't ask](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) criteria.

Comment: I did not downvote the question. To hazard a guess, I'd say that it got downvoted because it seems too broad ('across Europe' probably means some 200-odd languages) and too specific (just one concept, *library*). Though it should be easy enough to find out its etymology for a speaker of any one of those languages, I doubt if such a list exists for all languages, in just one body of work.

Comment: @prash In that case, should I just delete the question? I wasn't sure myself whether these sorts of topics are ever the subjects of papers. That's one of the reasons I asked this question.

Comment: Seems a inner-Latin, Church culture, historical issue. Comparing the Church history and epochs and works in Latin might help. "bibliotek" more relating to the Bible than the more secular "libr".

Comment: *biblio* comes from the Greek, and just means 'book'. (Or scroll I guess?)

Comment: @curiousdannii yes and thanks for the correction, though just "bible" is more translated by the greek stem, bible/Bibel/bijbel. Maybe libr is from an newer history?

Comment: It's a perfectly good question, but I don't think that the etymology of cross-language cognates of a particular term is about linguistics.  That's why I'm voting to close it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms sharing one meaning, "library," and is therefore insufficiently general to be relevant to linguistics.  So I'm voting to close it.

Comment: I don't see why the question would be "too broad" (it asks for a book or a paper, so the answer could be a one liner (like, *The Origin of All Words*, John Doe, 2014). I also doubt that it is off-topic; we do not have a stackexchange for compared etymology, so where should it go if not here?

Comment: I have this impression that some people are eager to close questions that they don't know how to answer...

Comment: It seems to me that probably Welsh and Irish borrowed from English, or the other way round. Perhaps Maltese also borrowed from English; it would be a small but nice compensation for British colonialism against the island. Basque is way more of a mistery, though; it borders both Castillan *biblioteca* and French *bibliothèque", and the Euzkadi was never friendly visited by the people across the channel.

Comment: To notice, Portuguese and Castillian at least do have the words *livraria* and *librería*; it is just that they mean "bookshop", not "library".